# Open Redirect: Non-Constant URL Target of HTTP Redirect in strategy.controller.ts:StrategyController<constructor>.anonymous3.anonymous

Tags: node.js, security

```
 passport.authenticate(type, (error, _) => {
      if (error) {
        if (stateData && stateData.failureURL && 
         validUrl.isUri(`${stateData.failureURL}`)) {
          const link = `${stateData.failureURL}`;
          return res.redirect(link);
        }
        return next(error);
      } else {
        if (stateData && stateData.failureURL && validUrl.isUri(stateData.successURL)) {
          const link = stateData.successURL;
          return res.redirect(link);
        }
        return next(new Error('Invalid success URL'));
      }
    })(req, res, next);
```

at return res.redirect(link); the qwiet ai giving openredirect security issue in above code.